# ANT does not link JNI files

Tags: java, android, c++, ant, android-ndk

Compiled .apk is starting but has not translated & compiled neither java code nor cpp code. Instead of this ANT builder makes new java file and compilation goes with that template file. I didn't find any sufficient manuals to console/terminal building !without! IDE & Gradle (especially without Google's IDE).

### Project structure

Is:

```
/* / */
  /* cpp */
  jni
    com_example_jnihelloworld_jniactivity.h
    jniactivity.h
    jniactivity.cpp
    jniimplement.cpp
    Application.mk
    Android.mk
  libs
  obj
  /* java */
  src
    com
      example
        jnihelloworld
          jniactivity.java
  bin
    com
      example
        jnihelloworld
          jniactivity.class
  pcmp

ndk-build
android create project --target android-24 --name HelloJni --path .\pcmp --activity jniact --package com.example.jnihelloworld
ant debug -f .\pcmp
```

### Sources

Java file:

```
package com.example.jnihelloworld;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class jniactivity extends Activity {

  static {
    System.loadLibrary("myjni");
  }

  public native String getMessage();

  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    TextView textView = new TextView(this);
    textView.setText(getMessage());
    setContentView(textView);
  }
}
```

C++ file:

```
#include "com_example_jnihelloworld_jniactivity.h"
#include "jniactivity.h"


JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL Java_com_example_jnihelloworld_jniactivity_getMessage (JNIEnv *pEnv, jobject pThis) {
    std::cout << "One" << std::endl;
    return pEnv->NewStringUTF("Hello from native code!");
}
```

### ANT script file (automatic generated):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project name="HelloJni" default="help">

    <!-- The local.properties file is created and updated by the 'android' tool.
         It contains the path to the SDK. It should *NOT* be checked into
         Version Control Systems. -->
    <property file="local.properties" />

    <!-- The ant.properties file can be created by you. It is only edited by the
         'android' tool to add properties to it.
         This is the place to change some Ant specific build properties.
         Here are some properties you may want to change/update:

         source.dir
             The name of the source directory. Default is 'src'.
         out.dir
             The name of the output directory. Default is 'bin'.

         For other overridable properties, look at the beginning of the rules
         files in the SDK, at tools/ant/build.xml

         Properties related to the SDK location or the project target should
         be updated using the 'android' tool with the 'update' action.

         This file is an integral part of the build system for your
         application and should be checked into Version Control Systems.

         -->
    <property file="ant.properties" />

    <!-- if sdk.dir was not set from one of the property file, then
         get it from the ANDROID_HOME env var.
         This must be done before we load project.properties since
         the proguard config can use sdk.dir -->
    <property environment="env" />
    <condition property="sdk.dir" value="${env.ANDROID_HOME}">
        <isset property="env.ANDROID_HOME" />
    </condition>

    <!-- The project.properties file is created and updated by the 'android'
         tool, as well as ADT.

         This contains project specific properties such as project target, and library
         dependencies. Lower level build properties are stored in ant.properties
         (or in .classpath for Eclipse projects).

         This file is an integral part of the build system for your
         application and should be checked into Version Control Systems. -->
    <loadproperties srcFile="project.properties" />

    <!-- quick check on sdk.dir -->
    <fail
            message="sdk.dir is missing. Make sure to generate local.properties using 'android update project' or to inject it through the ANDROID_HOME environment variable."
            unless="sdk.dir"
    />

    <!--
        Import per project custom build rules if present at the root of the project.
        This is the place to put custom intermediary targets such as:
            -pre-build
            -pre-compile
            -post-compile (This is typically used for code obfuscation.
                           Compiled code location: ${out.classes.absolute.dir}
                           If this is not done in place, override ${out.dex.input.absolute.dir})
            -post-package
            -post-build
            -pre-clean
    -->
    <import file="custom_rules.xml" optional="true" />

    <!-- Import the actual build file.

         To customize existing targets, there are two options:
         - Customize only one target:
             - copy/paste the target into this file, *before* the
               <import> task.
             - customize it to your needs.
         - Customize the whole content of build.xml
             - copy/paste the content of the rules files (minus the top node)
               into this file, replacing the <import> task.
             - customize to your needs.

         ***********************
         ****** IMPORTANT ******
         ***********************
         In all cases you must update the value of version-tag below to read 'custom' instead of an integer,
         in order to avoid having your file be overridden by tools such as "android update project"
    -->
    <!-- version-tag: 1 -->
    <import file="${sdk.dir}/tools/ant/build.xml" />

</project>
```

Comment: What does your ant build script(s) look like? Also, why not build with gradle from the commandline? It'll be much less of a hassle than trying to stick with Ant.

Comment: I have added ANT script file, Michael.